# jQuery: How to send $(this) as plugin parameter

Tags: jquery, plugins, parameters, this

I created a jQuery plugin that manage the input content (max chars, preg match,...). And I would like to use it like this:

```
$("form textarea.count-chars").smartInput({

    counterDiv: "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "-chars-left",
    maxChars: 128

});
```

This means, the plugin takes all the textareas with a class "count-chars" and display a countdown chars in a div block with **the same id as the corresponding textarea + "-chars-left"**. And here the problem is...

console.log revealed that **$(this).attr("id")** refer to **undefined** !!!

So: How can I use the attributes of an input (for example) as a plugin parameter?

Here is the plugin: http://github.com/hassinus/smartInput

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I can think of right now is to use `.each()`

```
$("form textarea.count-chars").each(function() {
    var ta = $(this);
    ta.smartInput({
        counterDiv: "#" + ta.attr("id") + "-chars-left",
        maxChars: 128
    });
});
```

Comment: Tested and Approved. Thanks a lot for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set `this` there.

Only in callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `$(this).attr("id")` is undefined in the code you show is because at that point `this` has nothing to do with your jQuery "form textarea.count-chars" selector so `this` is *not* the "current" element being processed. `$(this).attr("id")` (along with the rest of that object literal) is evaluated first and the result is passed to your plugin.

If you need to retrieve some attribute for each matching element you need to do it inside your plugin. Or setup your plugin to take another parameter that is a callback function and then you can supply a function to somehow process the individual elements.

Following is a rough outline of how to do it:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.smartInput = function(options) {      
     this.each(function() {
        // get associated div's id via the supplied callback,
        // passing the current element to that callback            
        var associatedDivId = options.callback.call(this,this);

        // do something with the id
     });    
  };
})( jQuery );


$(("form textarea.count-chars").smartInput({
   maxChars : 128,
   callback : function(el) { return $(this).attr("id"); }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. But using function callback seems a little bit tricky! Phil solution seems simpler (to use and keeps the plugin as it is). In all cases, I need to reed deeper for **$(this)** use. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess I assumed you wouldn't want to use `.each()` to call the plugin one element at a time because normally plugins are designed to handle multiple elements. Another way to implement it would be to add a `data-chars-left-id` attribute to your inputs and specify the associated id right there in the markup - then your plugin can simply read the id from there rather than taking it as a parameter/option - you could do the same with the `maxChars`, and then your call to the plugin would just be `$("form textarea.count-chars").smartInput();` and it would figure out the rest.